# How to center a paragraph with larger margins?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am hoping to get something like the following where the paragraph is centered and left-aligned.

Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvQKC.png)

Comment: Something similar to `\begin{quote} ..... \end{quote}`?

Comment: You should take a look at the `changepage` package and its `adjustwidth` environment.

Comment: On the image, the targeted text seems to be justified and not left aligned , as usually produced by the `quote` environment. If you want left aligned text you have to add `\raggedright` inside the environment before the text.